Cambiar idioma Mysql a español
Hola estoy iniciándome en base de datos y me facilitaría mucho cambiar el idioma en MySQL a español, sobretodo el de los mensajes de error. Gracias por la ayuda.

Ya que estamos en las iniciaciones, también puedes empezar con el inglés, ya que es un idioma fundamental en programación. Y no creo que haya forma de cambiar MySQL a español, simplemente porque no es necesario.

Esto no tiene que ver con problema relacionados a la programacion, esto tiene que ver con configuracion del servidor de donde se ejecuta la base de datos y la configuracion de ambos... ademas no creo que MySQL tenga tal cosa que buscas... casi todo lo que tiene que ver con desarrollo esta en ingles.

ademas te recomiendo hacer el [tour], hay te dice como funciona este sitio.

Traductor o aprender Inglés, no hay de otra. Y si quieres un buen consejo: APRENDE INGLÉS, eso te va a servir en todo, toda la vida...

Gracias por el consejo no había pensado en aprender Inglés...

Para cambiar el idioma de los mensajes de error necesitas modificar la variable lc_messages

[Traducción libre]
La configuración regional a utilizar para los mensajes de error. Por defecto es en_US. El servidor convierte el argumento en un nombre de idioma y lo combina con el valor de lc_messages_dir para producir la ubicación del archivo de mensajes de error. Consulte la Sección 12.12, "Configuración del idioma de los mensajes de error".

Ejemplo:

Para que el cambio sea temporal:
SET lc_messages = 'es_ES';
SELECT * FROM tabla_inexistente;

#1146 - Tabla '[DB_NAME].tabla_inexistente' no existe


Para que el cambio sea permanente:
Modificar el my.ini o my.cnf:
lc-messages=en_US




Muchisimas gracias probare el cambio permanente, pero por ahora el temporal funciona!! Gracias de verdad!!

En MariaDB, puedes modificar el archivo de configuración (my.cnf o my.ini). Agrega la línea lc_messages=es_ES en la sección [mariadb] y reinicia el servidor. También puedes cambiarlo temporalmente ejecutando el comando SQL SET GLOBAL lc_messages = 'es_ES'; en un cliente SQL.

Muchas gracias por tu respuesta!!
